# Transformation of multiple input files

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

Right now i am using this java (which receives one xml file parameter) method to perform XSLT transformation:

```
static public byte[] simpleTransform(byte[] sourcebytes, int ref_id) {   
    try {
        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(sourcebytes));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformations_list.get(ref_id).transformer.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(writer));
        return writer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();   
        return new byte[0];
    }   
}
```

And in my xslt file i am using the `document('f2.xml')` to refer to other transform related files.

I want to use my Java like this (get multiple xml files):

```
static public byte[] simpleTransform(byte[] f1, byte[] f2, byte[] f3, int ref_id)
```

An in my XSLT i don't want to call `document('f2.xml')` but refer to the object by using f2 received in my Java method.

Is there a way to do it? how do i refer to

> f2.xml

in my XSLT using this way?

Comment: @Erwin: Thanks for improving indentation and post language! But please do not edit away errors in code. This is something you should point out in a comment or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is in f1, f2 etc. Is it the URL of a document? or the XML document content itself?

There are two possible approaches you could consider.

One is to write a URIResolver. When you call document('f2.xml') Saxon will call your URIResolver to get the relevant document as a Source object. Your URIResolver could return a StreamSource initialized with a ByteArrayInputStream referring to the relevant btye[] value.

A second approach is to supply the documents as parameters to the stylesheet. You could declare a global parameter `<xsl:param name="f2" as="document-node()"/>` and then use `Transfomer.setParameter()` to supply the actual document; within the stylesheet, replace `document('f2.xml')` by `$f2`. Saxon will accept a Source object as the value supplied to setParameter, so you could again create a StreamSource initialized with a ByteArrayInputStream referring to the relevant btye[] value; alternatively (and perhaps better) you could pre-build the tree by calling a Saxon DocumentBuilder.

Comment: <xsl:param name="f2" as="document-node()"/> gives xml validation error: Attribute "as" is not allowed to appear in xsl:param

Comment: I tend to assume that people using Saxon are using XSLT 2.0. This error suggests you are using XSLT 1.0. (I assume you're using Saxon because you put the tag "saxon" on your question.) Time to upgrade!