# Java and XSLT: How to specify multiple input files to xslt in java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I have a set of xml files (each has a different structure and their number can vary) which I need to combine to form one xml file.

I generated an xslt file (used MapForce) which takes multiple xml files as input . Following snippet shows the input to the xslt file -

```
<xsl:param name="input" select="()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$input/@multiplier">
            <xsl:attribute name="multiplier" select="fn:string(.)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:sequence select="fn:string($input)"/>
```

I am using s9API to transform my input to the required output xml file -

```
InputStream stylesheetInputStream = new FileInputStream("xsltFile.xslt");

StreamSource input = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("input.xml"));
StreamResult output = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"));

TransformerFactory factory = net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Transformer t = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(stylesheetInputStream));

t.setParameter("input", new File[]{new File("source_1.xml"), new File("source_2.xml"), new File("source_3.xml")});                    


t.transform(input, output);
```

I keep getting an exception and for some reason, it is actually the output file that's mentioned in the error which is quite strange (and this file is empty, of course) -

```
Error on line 1 column 1 of output.xml:
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Premature end of file.
; SystemID: ; Line#: 90; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:425)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:178)
    at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Configuration.java:3516)
    at net.sf.saxon.lib.StandardCollectionURIResolver$FileExpander.map(StandardCollectionURIResolver.java:441)
    at net.sf.saxon.lib.StandardCollectionURIResolver$FileExpander.map(StandardCollectionURIResolver.java:321)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.MappingIterator.next(MappingIterator.java:56)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.ItemMappingIterator.next(ItemMappingIterator.java:83)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.ContextMappingIterator.next(ContextMappingIterator.java:52)
    at net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceExtent.<init>(SequenceExtent.java:105)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.DocumentOrderIterator.<init>(DocumentOrderIterator.java:31)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.DocumentSorter.iterate(DocumentSorter.java:101)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.processLeavingTail(ForEach.java:414)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:615)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:131)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:301)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:254)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:131)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:301)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:254)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:615)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:131)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:301)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:254)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:586)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:212)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1034)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1957)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1803)
    at com.test.Transform.performTransform(Transform.java:33)
    at com.test.Transform.main(Transform.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:90)
```

does my xslt file specify input correctly? If not, how to specify multiple files as input?
Or am I incorrectly setting the parameters in my code?

I found a related query here - 
[Transformation of multiple input files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232128/tranformation-of-multiple-input-files)

One of the post mentions using `<xsl:param name="f2" as="document-node()"/>` but how to specify multiple files?

**Update**:
I am unable to post an answer so just editing my question -

Finally figured it out.....

I use MapForce and am not terribly familiar with xslt so I can't explain the expression below too much but conceptually I did this -

I used a comma separated string (containing list of files) as input which is then tokenized.

```
<xsl:param name="listOfFiles" as="xs:string" required="yes"/>

<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($listOfFiles, replace(',', '(\.|\$|\^|\{|\[|\(|\||\)|\*|\+|\?|\\)', '\\$1'))">
```

for my java code -

```
t.setParameter("listOfFiles", "file1.xml,file2.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace includes a CollectionURIResolver and this means that your source code must be calling the collection() function, which isn't in evidence in the source code snippet you have shown us.

There are all sorts of ways of tackling this. You can use collection(), or you can pass in a list of URIs, or you can pass in a single string containing a semicolon-separated or tab-separated sequence of URIs, to be tokenized inside your stylesheet.

If you want to pass a sequence of strings as a parameter value then you're better off using the s9api interface rather than JAXP. JAXP is oriented to XSLT 1.0, which doesn't have a list of strings as a recognized data type.

The XSLT fragment you showed is pretty weird, it is creating a set of attributes called "multiplier" from the multiplier attributes of a set of elements passed as the input; that doesn't relate to anything in the JAXP calling sequence that you showed us.